# Apache Camel: threads per endpoint

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-camel, endpoint

I can't get more than 64 simultaneous calls per endpoint, regardless of what I set the threads value to. Is there another parameter, or is 64 a hard limit?

My RouteBuilder:

```
public void configure() {
        ...
        from("jetty:http://0.0.0.0:7076...").routeId(MDP_ROUTE).threads(200, 250, "mdpEndpointThread").loadBalance(router).to(<URL1><URL2><URL3>);
}
```

Camel version 2.16, Using Jetty

Comment: what happens after 64 simultaneous calls and how are you making these calls?

Comment: It keeps working, but I cant use more parallell calls, i.e. a client have to wait until there is a free thread. I'm making the calls using a number of  simple apache HttpClients.

Comment: The complete consumer: jetty:http://0.0.0.0:7076/mdr/api/ifmdr?matchOnUriPrefix\=true&amp;enableMultipartFilter=false

Comment: A complete producer: jetty:http://localhost:6080/say/hello1?bridgeEndpoint\=true&amp;throwExceptionOnFailure\=false&amp;disableStreamCache\=true